# "The Transaction has aborted" exception on disposing the Transaction Scope

Tags: c#, transactionscope

The code shown here worked fine without any error on quality site, but the same code is causing an error

> The Transaction has aborted

on the production site.

The error occurs on dispose of the scope. Please help me resolve this issue.

I did check:

- Network DTC Setting on server and database server
- Both sites (Quality and Production) are on same Server (Server A) and database also on same server (Server B)

Code:

```
option.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
option.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

using (_objTransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
{
    //..Open Connection
    //..Process the Document
    //..Update Additional information in Table2 about document(Delete/Insert)   
    //..Update Location Information in Table3 about document(Delete/Insert)
    //..Delete the Document in Table4 in Differant Database on Differant Server(WCF Service)
    //..Update the Checksum of the Document and Metadata in Table1
    //..Delete Lock Entry From Table5   
    //..Close Connection
    //..Commit Transaction Scope
}
```

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory - you need to decide how to deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: there is no any error...

Comment: Shouldn't this bit `//..Close Connection
    //..Commit Transaction Scope` be other way around?

Comment: If your comments within the using block are correct, I think you want to commit before you close the connection.